# Laravel 5.3 date validator: equal to or after start_date

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I'm using Laravel 5.3 to validate start_date and end_date for an event.
end_date should be equal to start_date or the after date. `end_date >= start_date`

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'start_date'    => 'required|date',
    'end_date'      => 'required|date|after:start_date',
]);
```

I tried to use **after**, but it only works for end_date > start_date.
Of course, I can add custom rule using `Validator::extend`, but I'd like to know if we can do without adding custom rule.

Is there any way to add negative rule or add >= rule?

Thanks

Comment: Not a Proper solution but if you dont want to create custom validation you can subtract 1 day from start date and then validate using after

Comment: Well, you could make a new variable with the start_at - 1 day and pass that in instead, perhaps not ideal but it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but could we do without calling validator methods twice?

Comment: Yes you can if you insert the variable with 1 day less in $data variable

Comment: Just above the validator manipulate $data variable

Comment: Thanks @Rohit, Good solution, but I'd like to find a validator without doing additional work for that.

Comment: add costume validate rule, https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: @RaghavRangani Thats not wanted from the person that posed the question.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'start_date'    => 'required|date',
    'end_date'      => 'required|date|after_or_equal:start_date',
]);
```

Use **after_or_equal**

Comment: Helped alot, Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

**Be careful when you set a validation rule `after_or_equal:now` and `date_format` with a format without hours, minutes or seconds!**

For example:

```php
$validationRules = [
    'my_time_start' => [
        'date_format:Y-m-d',// format without hours, minutes and seconds.
        'after_or_equal:now'
    ]
];
```

Laravel passing all date fields into the `strtotime()` function.
Including `now` string.
And `strtotime('now')` will return a unix timestamp **with current minutes, hours and seconds**.

For example, the today date is `2020-05-03`.
When you send a date value `2020-05-03` into your script, Laravel will pass 2 values into the `strtotime()` for compare:

```php
strtotime('2020-05-03'); // always 1588489200
strtotime('now'); // NOT PREVIOUS VALUE, a different value each second, timestamp including current minutes, hour and seconds.
```

And you will always fail a validation (exclude a 1 second of the day).

To fix it, you should use:

```php
$validationRules = [
    'my_time_start' => [
        'date_format:Y-m-d',// format without hours, minutes and seconds.
        'after_or_equal:' . date('Y-m-d'), // not 'now' string
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can also use `after_or_equal` and `before_or_equal` when using at least Laravel version `5.3.31`. This may help to avoid having to upgrade to a higher Laravel version.

Answer (score 4):

upgarate to **5.4** and you can use after_or_equal
see
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-after-or-equal